# Recommend Automated test tools for cross platform including IE and .NET software

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, agile

I'm working in an QA team.

We do the automated work from the scratch. So many testing methods may be anti-pattern or disobey some discipline.

We pay lots of effort on test web pages on our products.

Our test cases are based on `Robot framework` and use the selenium library for testing web pages.

I found my members write those code by looking up  the html source code to find the `id` or `name` of the `DOM element`. (Because some of element in DOM without ID.)

Even worse, the same function buttons' `DOM id` are differs from many product.

So I just think the way we build the automated testing code is too slow.

I thought if there is an tool that can record our all actions'  on web pages and turn it into Robot framework script  or other testing framework scripts is more effective ?

If there any good tool for the purpose ?

Second.

We test the `.NET` software by auto-it.
Is there any GUI Software testing tool can cross platforms even on `Android` or `iOS` ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of test automation tools out there, Selenium being the common cross platform option (which is free). You can use the Selenium IDE to record your test cases from Firefox, as long as your back-end doesn't generate different code based on the type of browser connecting, it can play beck these tests against a multitude of browsers.

Other options that come to mind are Microsoft CodedUI tests (part of Visual Sudio Premium and higher), which in turn can drive Selenium to execute the tests on Chrome and Firefox, no direct iOS and Android support though. For that you can look at [PerfectoMobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/), which as far as I can remember can integrate into the Microsoft tool suite.

Others like [DevExpress Testcafe](http://testcafe.devexpress.com/) offer really neat record and playback features, though they use Javascript and NodeJS to run the tests. They support connecting mobile browsers as well, as long as they're able to host their javascript based test runner, pretty nifty if you ask me :).

Telerik offers a cross browser [testing framework](http://www.telerik.com/products/free-testing-framework/overview.aspx), and their Test Studio adds recording capabilities, they have a single API to author cross browser tests. No features for Mobile testing as far as I know.

There might be others as well, plus you can combine some of these frameworks with a Specification by Example like tool such as [SpecFlow](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/search/label/SpecFlow).

On StackOverflow we do not recommend any specific tool, since it's hard to give a solid answer on what's the best tool. The context is way too important to make that decision based on the 20 lines of your question.